# SQL Sub query and case statment

Tags: sql

I got unique ID's from POS table by using the below code where now I need to get the address information next to it comparing them with customer master table.

```
select 
subqueries.id
from
(
select (cust_key) as id from dbo.pos
union
select (disti_key) as id from dbo.pos
union 
select (reseller_key) as id from dbo.pos
)subqueries
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: So... `inner join customerMaster mst on mst.id = subqueries.id` should be what you want?

Comment: Re. comments like "add the tag of the database you are using" : I suggest those people take a careful look at the definition of the tag "database" and in particular to the part where it says "The term database should not be confused with Database Management System (DBMS)".

Comment: @ErwinSmout: John did not suggest to add the tag `database` but a tag (and only one) for the database _product_  that is being used. Tagging a question with MySQL **and** SQL Server usually doesn't make sense. Many people do that in the hope to attract more readers, but it's actually detrimental.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the customer master table has a primary key column `id` and let it have the name `customers`

```
select subqueries.id, c.adress
from (select (cust_key) as id from pos
      union
      select (disti_key) as id from pos
      union 
      select (reseller_key) as id from pos
     ) subqueries
join customers c on subqueries.id = c.id
```

Comment: yes now getting the address, street, country fields from customer master table to match with subqueries result

Comment: @Harry, that is already part of the answer but I only added an example field, `c.adress`, since I do not know the content of the customer table. Just add any column needed, `c.street`, `c.country` etc